# Is it possible to let gnu cpp preserve include macro?

Tags: c++, c, gnu, c-preprocessor

I'm using `gnu cpp` for some tests and hope it preserves the *#include* macro and extends other user-defined macro meanwhile. Is it possible?
Here's a piece of code(foo.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NEWLINE(str) str "\n"
int main(){
  puts(NEWLINE("foo"));
}
```

And I hope the result of `cpp foo.c` to be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  puts("foo\n");
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example?

Comment: And why exactly do you ask? You could copy-paste the preprocessed output after some given point (e.g. after the last `#include`), but even that is not very sensible: you want to read `MAP_FAILED` not `((void *) -1)` in your source code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the preprocessor to preprocess only certain parts but not others. This is generally not possible. The only way to do this is to add conditions to the source, i.e. use e.g. `#ifdef` and `#endif` around the parts you want expanded, and pass a define on the command line to the preprocessor.

Comment: So I have to let `cpp gnu` ignore those _#define_ macros first and preprocess for others?

Comment: @HongxuChen No, you have to use [conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) techniques to tell the preprocessor which part it should preprocess and which part it should not.

Comment: Got it! I know what I can do now, although the requirement is a bit different:-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a script to comment out every #include, run cpp and then remove these comments.

Comment: It might not behave as wanted. Imagine some first included header `#define`-ing something which a secondly included header would test with `#ifdef` (and this is a common case, often hidden)

Comment: You're right but if I understand correctly what @Hongxu Chen want `#define`  in a header don't have to apply outside of this file.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. However, the line information is usually available in lines starting with `#` in the preprocessor output.

You could use perhaps some other preprocessor like e.g. [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP)